# Yield called too often by zip?

Tags: python, yield

In the following code a count is zipped with a two element list. I expected the counter to be called two times but it is called three times. Why?

```
def equivalent_count(start=0, step=1):
    """From python docs for itertools.count."""
    n = start
    while True:
        print('count in loop =', n)
        yield n
        n += step

c = equivalent_count()
l = [0, 1]

for i, j in zip(c, l):
    pass
```

The output is:

```
count in loop = 0
count in loop = 1
count in loop = 2
```

The docs for `zip` state, "The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap `c` and `l`:

```
for i, j in zip(l, c):
    pass
```

to get only two prints:

```
count in loop = 0
count in loop = 1
```

Now `l` is exhausted first and `next(c)` is not called a third time as in your version.

Comment: This leads to a new rule (for me at least) that the ```itertools.count``` generator call must come last in the arguments to ```zip```.

Answer (score 3):

Because each iteration of `c` is calculated before the equivalent one of `l`, so Python doesn't know that `l` is exhausted yet. You could see this if you replaced `l` with a generator as well:

```
def gen_l(lst):
    for l in lst:
        print 'gen_l called'
        yield l

c = equivalent_count()
l = gen_l([0, 1])
for i, j in zip(c, l):
    pass
```

which outputs:

```
count in loop = 0
gen_l called
count in loop = 1
gen_l called
count in loop = 2
```

Comment: You can also see that there are only two prints when you issue `for i, j in zip(l, c): pass`.

Comment: Here you can see an implementation https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1364858e6ec7abfe04d92b7796ae8431eda87a7a/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2480